# How to save the previous instance of embedded arguments in robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework, gherkin, keyword-argument

I am trying to achieve one scenario which I am not able to do. PFB the scenario:

```
"${ABX}" doing some operation to "${XYZ}"
    ${result}  Set variable  "${ABX}"
    Log  ${result}
    ${callee}  Set variable  "${XYZ}"
    Log  ${callee}
    Run keyword if  ${result}=="${ABX}"  Keyword1
    ...  ELSE  Keyword2

**Test case in Gherkin Style:**
    Given some operation xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyzzzz
    When "Sam" doing some operation to "Tom"
```

Here I am passing the `Sam` in `abx` and `Tom` in `xyz` that will do operation according to `Sam` and `Tom`.

My questions are as below:

1. How I will exchange the user in test case keeping in mind that I have to  retain the properties of `Sam` and `Tom`? For example:

   ```
   **Given some operation xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyzzzz
   When "Tom" doing some operation to "Sam"**
   ```
2. How to be fully dynamic in this scenario provided we will take any user not just `Sam` and `Tom` with the mentioned properties of each user?
3. What will be the correction in above code specially in if else because in any scenario it is not going to `Keyword2`?

Comment: It is kind of unclear what you are trying to accomplish. What properties are you referring to? What is the purpose of `${callee}`? You want to store the previous `abx` in `result` in your example?

Comment: @BenceKaulics- I am trying to manipulate two user profiles in gherkin style. I am here referring to the properties of gherkin style and embedded arguments.$callee is just a variable which is storing just the value of "${XYZ}". I don want to just store but later on to evaluate also the condition that if this user --.

Comment: In what scope do you want to store the data, suite or test case?

Comment: @BenceKaulics - The scope is limited to test case.

Comment: Then perhaps the [Set Test Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Test%20Variable) keyword is what you need.

Answer (score -1):

1. This is positional arguments. There are no "properties" retaining.
2. The "properties" should have some mapping to users, so it can be using a dictionary.
3. The way it is coded, ${result] is always equal to ${ABX}.

Comment: @helio- Will you provide a working solution for this scenario ?

Comment: What is the condition to run Keyword2? How would you run it in a non ELSE condition?
If Tom and Sam are dictionaries their properties are retained. It is not clear what you want to do.